# Run FUSION/LDV programs from Python

Tags: python, fusion

I have been working with [FUSION/LDV: Software for LIDAR Data Analysis and Visualization](https://forsys.cfr.washington.edu/FUSION/fusion_overview.html) for LAS data processing.

Particularly I am using such commands as **GridSurfaceCreate** - to create a gridded surface model; **CanopyModel** - to create a canopy surface model using a LIDAR point cloud and especially I am interested in **CanopyMaxima** module which uses canopy model to identify individual trees. All commands can be found in FUSION manual [here](http://forsys.cfr.washington.edu/software/fusion/FUSION_manual.pdf)!

Currently I am running the programme manually from command line, however as all other work that I am doing is in Python, I was wondering if there is a chance to call FUSION/LDV functions from Python or more specific, is it possible to implement the FUSION programs in Python code?

The most important step would be to use CanopyMaxima for tree detection as this algorith indicated the best result for my test area.

Comment: As a side note, have you considered moving your workflow to R using the lidR package? lidR excels at individual tree detection. More details on lidR: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/index.html. Details on individual tree detection: https://github.com/r-lidar/lidR/wiki/Segment-individual-trees-and-compute-metrics-(Part-2)

Comment: Thanks! I have tried the R workflow, as well as lidR package, however, the obtained results did not give the best accuracy compared to my reference data. That's why I stick to the Fusion package, as it gives the most accurate tree detection results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the way with import os:

```
import os

output = r'W:\...\test'
chm_dtm = r'W:\...\test\chm.dtm'

TheCommand = 'W:\\FUSION\\CanopyMaxima.exe' + ' /threshold:6 /wse:2.2,0.16,0,0,0 /shape /summary ' + chm_dtm + ' ' + output

os.system(TheCommand)

The result:
test_HighPoints.shp
test_Polygons.shp
test_treelist.csv
test_treelist_summary.csv
```